# QGIS MySql database queries over 4000

Tags: qgis, mysql

When i open file of QGIS 2.6.1 with 32 layers whose tables all come from the same database, i see that by just opening the file, QGIS already sends 4100+ "SELECT..."-questions to the database, and around 2000 "DESCRIBE..."-questions.

The interaction with QGIS becomes very slow this way.
Any idea which settings might cause this or is this by defaut?

I have pasted the SERVERLOGS on pastebin and what i see is a lot of queries like:

`SELECT srid FROM geometry_columns WHERE f_table_name = 'vegetation'`

http://pastebin.com/pKSgK99y

I do not have any of these columns, no "srid", no "geometry_columns", no "f_table_name" defined in my database. Should these be in database? (the qgis-database works, but very slow)

Comment: Are there any requirements for storing spatial data in a MySql Table? I see that when storing spatial data in PostGis, you need a geometry_columns table and all that. Looking over the SQL's, it's clear that QGIS wants to access these, but when i add these tables to the MySql-database, i still get the same amount of queries to the server.